# How to constrain class template by disabling type argument of specialization itself, and why does(n't) it work?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is it currently possible to constrain a class template that rejects type argument which is the specialization of the class template itself without using `static_assert`?

Since I cannot use `requires` expression to check if it is a valid typename, I have to create a class template instantiation validator that checks whether the class template passed is valid with template arguments:

```cpp
template <template <typename...> typename Temp, typename... Ts>
    requires requires { typename Temp<Ts...>; }
constexpr bool is_valid() { return true; }

template <template <typename...> typename, typename...>
constexpr bool is_valid() { return false; }

template <template <typename...> typename Temp, typename... Ts>
concept valid_instantiation = is_valid<Temp, Ts...>();
```

Since failed `static_assert` emits a hard error, just like this one:

```cpp
template <typename>
class Hello;

template <typename>
inline constexpr bool is_hello_v = false;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_hello_v<Hello<T>> = true;

template <typename T>
class Hello {
  static_assert(!is_hello_v<T>);
};

static_assert(valid_instantiation<Hello, int>);
static_assert(!valid_instantiation<Hello, Hello<int>>);
```

The second static assertion sure didn't compile unless I remove that `!` that returns `true` which is not what I expected.

What I want to have is to silent the error and replace the `static_assert`, so that:

```cpp
static_assert(valid_instantiation<Hello, int>);
static_assert(!valid_instantiation<Hello, Hello<int>>);
```

can be valid.

For the first static assertion, the `Hello<int>` instantiation is accepted just fine, while the second static assertion, `Hello<Hello<int>>` instantiation should be rejected because the template argument passed is the instantiation of the class template itself but I have no knowledge what constraints I'll be using to achieve these.

It's ok if it is impossible to do so, or otherwise.

Comment: What exactly do you consider SFINAE friendly? There's no function shown here and SFINAE on types is afaik non-standard.

Comment: `static_assert(!requires { typename Hello<Hello<int>>; });` This won't work *anyway*.

Comment: "*I want to have an SFINAE-friendly version.*" It's not clear exactly what you want here. Do you want a concept that filters such things out, such that you can constrain some other template against this? That is, can a user use `Hello<Hello<T>>` in certain circumstances, or do you always want that to not work?

Comment: what if someone inherit yours? `struct B:Hello<A>;` `Hello<B>;`?. Actually I don't see how the constraint you propose is needed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: the current code doesn't demonstrate the idea (the assert doesn't depend on T anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it is what you want, but

```
template <typename T> struct is_Hello;
template <typename T> requires (!is_Hello<T>::value) class Hello;

template <typename T> struct is_Hello : std::false_type{};
template <typename T> struct is_Hello<Hello<T>> : std::true_type{};

template <typename T>
requires (!is_Hello<T>::value) // So Hello<Hello<T>> is not possible
class Hello
{
// ...
};
```

Not sure how you want to SFINAE or test it (the trait seems equivalent), as `Hello<Hello<T>>` cannot exist.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s93En1x3z)